# obtener los parametros al usar auto.arima

Tags: r

Como obtener los parametros al usar auto.arima package en R?

es decir: de alguna manera llamar a ARIMA4 y que me entregue un argumento de tipo string de este estilo:
  ARIMA(2,1,0)(2,0,0)[12]

Una forma manual de comprobarlo es:

```
 train<-ts(data,start=c(2010,1),frequency=365)
    ARIMA4<-auto.arima(train)

    # llamada a Arima4
        > ARIMA4

        Series: train    
 ARIMA(2,1,0)(2,0,0)[12]                    

    Coefficients:
              ar1      ar2    sar1    sar2
          -0.6493  -0.3009  0.3995  0.3388
    s.e.   0.0864   0.0846  0.0885  0.0938

    sigma^2 estimated as 453046:  log likelihood=-1057.19
    AIC=2124.39   AICc=2124.86   BIC=2138.84
```

Hipotesis,
Me gustaria guardar en una variable(tenga logica o no) los parametros de arima.

```
>parametros
ARIMA(2,1,0)(2,0,0)[12]
```

Comment: En lugar de publicar la respuesta a tu pregunta inicial en el cuerpo de la pregunta inicial deberías responder tú mismo a tu pregunta y aceptarla para que otros puedan ver la solución cuando la busquen. Respecto a la actualización de tu pregunta con una nueva pregunta, lo mejor es que abras una nueva pregunta. Echa un ojo [aquí para saber cómo funciona el sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Como respuesta, en lugar de como comentario :-) Y acéptala como resuelta, así otros pueden saber que es una solución válida.

Comment: Se agradece los comentario, perdona al respecto que soy bastante noob.

Comment: No pasa nada. Nadie nace aprendido y para eso estamos, para ayudarnos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontrada solución:

añadiendo al modelo : "$arma"

```
ARIMA4$arma 
>[1] 2 0 2 0 12 1 0
```

Un "mejor formato":

```
paste("arima",list(ARIMA4$arma)) 
>"arima c(2, 0, 2, 0, 12, 1, 0)"
```

Es posible que haya una mejor solución para un formato mas elegante.